# Zenity list dialog from variables

Tags: command-line, bash, zenity

I have a bash script which looks like this:

```
column_names="--column=\"TargetDir\" --column=\"TargetPage_ID\" --column=\"TargetTitle\""
row="\"Target Dir 1\" 1 \"TargetTitle 1\""

echo "column_name is: [$column_names]"
echo "row is: [$row]"

zenity --list --title="list" $column_names $row
```

But when I run that, I see an strange dialog:

[image]

You can see there are two rows displayed instead of one (each word is unidentified as value of a column). Also this is the output in terminal:

```
column_name is: [--column="TargetDir" --column="TargetPage_ID" --column="TargetTitle"]
row is: ["Target Dir 1" 1 "TargetTitle 1"]
```

But when I copy printed values of `column_name` and `row` in terminal in this way:

```
zenity --list --title="list" --column="TargetDir" --column="TargetPage_ID" --column="TargetTitle" "Target Dir 1" 1 "TargetTitle 1"
```

I get a true list dialog:

[image]

What is wrong in script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're building a command line, always use arrays. It saves a lot of trouble in quoting:

```
column_names=(--column=TargetDir --column=TargetPage_ID --column=TargetTitle)
row=("Target Dir 1" 1 "TargetTitle 1")
```

Note how only the necessary quotes (to protect the spaces) are left now.

When using an array `a`, `"${a[@]}"` will expand the elements exactly as is, without causing problems with whitespace.
So:

```
zenity --list --title="list" "${column_names[@]}" "${row[@]}"
```

Try running `printf` instead of `echo` using your original variables, you might see what breaks:

```
printf "%s\n" $column_names $row
```

I'm not even going to try to explain what broke in the original quoting. :shudder: